# Apply condition based on probability in vector

Tags: r, probability

Sorry, this is kind of a mess but looking for some advice.

I am trying to simulate population growth with environmental stochasticity. I have created a vector of probabilities that any of the 10 patch sizes I am using will experience a catostrophic event that will reduce population sizes by 75%. I want to apply it within a function. So basically I need to have the function run and determine the population size for the next step, but then apply the probability for that patch size to determine whether or not the catastrophic event will occur before the new population size gets stored in the matrix.

So I basically want to do something like an If/Then, but instead of defining the "If" parameters I want to apply the stored probabilities. I've searched around without much luck but I am assuming this can't be all that difficult to do. Thanks!

```
d0 <- c(0.5, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05 ) # chance that a catastrophic 
# disturbance will reduce population for each patch size, assuming that rates of disturbance 
# are much higher in small patches. 

cat <- .25 # disturbance factor, assume that during catastrophic event 2/3 of animals are 
#removed, I want to multiply this by the population size within each time step at the frequency 
#defined in d0. I could probably make this into a function but I still need to know 
# how to use the probability to decide when to apply it.

# Ricker model (N_t+1=N_t*exp(r*(1-N_t/K)))

Ricker = function(nt, r, k0, d0) { #setup the Ricker function 
  nt1 = (nt*exp(r*(1-nt/k0))) # Run Ricker model
  nt1 = ((nt1*cat)) ### Here I would apply the probability, and when necessary the 
# disturbance factor. I.E. Breeding season happens then there is a very harsh winter 
# and many individuals die.
  return(nt1) #return the value of (Nt+1) 
} 

for(t in 1:(tf-1)) { #loop through time 
  n[t+1,] = Ricker(n[t,],r,k0) #step through Ricker 
}
```

I ended up doing something similar to what @Marius suggested and it seems to be working pretty well, thanks everyone for the input!

```
Ricker = function(nt, r, k0, d0) { #setup the Ricker function 
  nt1 = (nt*exp(r*(1-nt/k0))) # Run Ricker model
for(d in 1:(length(d0))) { # Create loop to test each patch for disturbance probability
dice_rolls = runif(length(d0)) # Generate random uniforms for each element in d0.
nt1 = ifelse(dice_rolls < d0, nt1 * cat, nt1) # If the'dice roll' is less than the corresponding element of d0 # the patch experiences the disturbance
  }
    return(nt1) #return the value of (Nt+1) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your model right you want:

```
Ricker = function(nt, r, k0, d0) { #setup the Ricker function 
    nt1 = (nt*exp(r*(1-nt/k0))) # Run Ricker model
    # Generate random uniforms for each element in d0. If the 
    # 'dice roll' is less than the corresponding element of d0, 
    # the patch experiences the disturbance
    dice_rolls = runif(length(d0))
    nt1 = ifelse(dice_rolls < d0, nt1 * cat, nt1)
    return(nt1) #return the value of (Nt+1) 
}
```

To see how this works, check out a simple simulation of how `dice_rolls < d0` operates: you can see that it treats each element of `d0` separately and
generates long-run averages that approximate the desired probabilities:

```
d0 <- c(0.5, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05)

n_catastrophes = numeric(length = length(d0))
for (sim_num in 1:1000) {
    dice_rolls = runif(length(d0))
    n_catastrophes = n_catastrophes + (dice_rolls < d0)
}
# Number of times each patch had a catastrophe in the simulation
print(n_catastrophes)
# Simulated probabilities
print(n_catastrophes / 1000)
```

Comment: I used your code in a for loop and it spits out results that seem plausible but I'm not totally sure that its actually cycling through the respective proportions.

Comment: @KatieSmith: Try adding `print(dice_rolls < d0)` within your `Ricker` function and you will see that it generates a separate `TRUE`/`FALSE` value for each element of `d0`, no extra looping required. I'll add some quick simulation code to show you how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting this right, you want a vector of values that represent either no catastrophic event, or a catastrophic event, with probabilities equal to d0?

You can sample a vector c(1.0, 0.25) with weighted probabilities based on d0, i.e. first entry is 50/50, last entry is only 5% catastrophic loss...etc.

For each loop, stochasticly draw your cat vector with:

```
cat <- unlist(lapply(d0, function(x) sample(c(1.0, 0.25), size=1, prob=c(1-x, x))))
```

and stick that in your loop after you run the Ricker model